# How to compile a docker-ce makefile?

Tags: docker, docker-ce

I have the source code of `docker-ce` from github and I am trying to use it.

I want "Hello World" to be printed out if I use the command `'docker pull ubuntu'`. (the default is `'using default tag:...'`)

So I found the source code by `docker-ce/component/cli/cli/command/image/'pull.go'` and modified it.

But I don't know how to compile it to run it.

Would anyone help me out with compiling this?

I've tried the following:

There was `Makefile` in the `docker-ce` directory so I used the command `'make deb'` to compile but it says it failed

Answer (score 0):

Put the `Makefile` and your `Dockerfile` into the same directory and run :

```
make deb
```

which i believe contain the same command as bellow:

```
docker build -t $(APP_NAME) .
```

notice the **. (dot)** , it means to include all of the file inside of the directory where the `Dockerfile` reside .. and *$(APP_NAME)* is the name you want for your docker images that you've created.

and to run it :

```
docker run --name containerName -it imageName
```

the **containerName** is name of the container you want to create and the **imageName** is the name of image you just compiled using the previous command

it would be great if you could post the `Makefile` here..